# Minecart Issue - Shaking instead of Moving

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

[image]

The above is a screenshot of the underground 1-way subway I am creating in Minecraft survival 1.8.8.

In the situation in the image above, when I try to ride the minecart, the minecart shakes and ejects me instead of moving forward. It should be noted that the shaking also occurs when the block behind the minecart is removed.

What is going on here, and how do I fix it? Thank you.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**You're using the wrong rails**. Use power rails instead of activator rails. Power rails move minecarts, activator rails cause entities to exit a minecart (and also activate tnt carts)

Comment: Thank you very much! To a person new to Minecraft, those names are tricky.